# In How Many Ways Can We Define Derivatives?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-derivative

On real and complex manifolds, we can define derivatives either by limits, or by Lie brackets, or by product rule:
$$
(uv)'=u'v+v'u
$$

I wonder if there's other ways to define derivatives. They may not be on just manifolds, but also other structures.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)), which generalize the properties of a derivative to a linear map on an algebra over a field.